# Legality of `typedef struct foo {int bar};`

Tags: c, struct, typedef, language-lawyer

This question arises from the question [Is a struct {...}; a type or an unnamed variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877661/is-a-struct-a-type-or-an-unnamed-variable)

In that question, the OP asked about

```
typedef struct student_s {
    char* name;
    int age;
    double height;
    struct student_s* next;   
};
```

I am asking about the legality of the above. Is a diagnostic required when code containing the above is compiled (or to make it simpler, `typedef struct foo {int bar;};`)?

My take is that it is legal, that a diagnostic is not required from a language lawyer perspective. (Aside: I am not advocating using this. It is very worthy of a diagnostic. I would very much want the compiler to warn me if I mistakenly wrote code like the above.)

Section 6.7 of the C11 standard dictates the syntax of a declaration: *declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>* `;` Note that the *init-declarator-list* is optional. This might lead one to think that `typedef int;` is valid. It isn't because the standard also says that

> A declaration other than a static_assert declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration.

Thus `typedef int;` and `typedef struct {int bar};` are illegal because they do not declare a declarator, a tag, or a member of an enumeration.

On the other hand, it appears to me that `typedef struct foo {int bar;};` is legal because it does declare something. In particular, it declares and defines the `struct` tag `foo`.

Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: I think it declares `{ int bar; }`, you just can't do anything useful with it.

Comment: @David Hammen There is no declarator in this typedef.

Comment: @this - The standard (see my quote in the question) specifically excludes members of a struct or union. Thus `typedef struct {int bar;};` is illegal.

Comment: @DavidHammen { int bar; } is the declarator, in my opinion.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - My take is that the quoted text in the question pertains to a declaration statement. As a statement, `typedef struct foo {int bar};` certainly does declare something. It just doesn't declare a target for the typedef.

Comment: @this - No, it isn't. The parenthetical remark *other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union* in the quoted text specifically excludes `{int bar;}` as the declarator.

Comment: Regarding the closure votes, how can this question possibly be too broad? It is a yes-no question: Must a compliant implementation issue a diagnostic for `typedef struct foo {int bar};` ?

Comment: What this really shows is that a struct should not be typedef'd

Comment: `typedef struct x {...};` is the same as `struct x {...};`

Comment: @user3629249 it doesn't show that at all

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399898/is-the-typedef-name-optional-in-a-typedef-declaration . No idea why there are "too broad" votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6.7.1 Storage class specifiers defines `typedef` as a storage class specifier with the following comment : *The typedef specifier is called a ‘‘storage-class specifier’’ for syntactic convenience
only;*

And 6.7 Declaration contains:

Syntax:

- declaration:

  - declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub>
- declaration-specifiers:

  - storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
  - type-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
  - type-qualifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
  - function-specifier declaration-specifiers<sub>opt</sub>
- init-declarator-list:

  - init-declarator
  - init-declarator-list , init-declarator
- init-declarator:

  - declarator
  - declarator = initializer

First *constraint* is : *A declaration shall declare at least a declarator 
(other than the parameters of a function or
the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration*

As the init-declarator-list is optional in a declaration, provided a declarator or tag is declared, I would say that `typedef struct foo {int bar;};` is a declaration decomposed as `storage-class-specifier type-specifier` with no init-declarator. But as the type-specifier declares internally a tag (`foo`) the constraint is respected.

My conclusion is that such a construct is valid and only produces warning on compilers.

Comment: There is no declarator. foo is a structure tag.

Comment: @David Hammen  And I wrote this in my answer.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - I'm going to wait a while before accepting an answer, but this is my take as well. If someone could cite chapter and verse from any version of the C standard that says that `typedef struct foo {int bar;}` is illegal, I'd accept that. But I can't find such chapter and verse in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

In the quote you cited there is written that a declaration shall declare among other things a tag.

So this declaration

```
typedef struct student_s {
    char* name;
    int age;
    double height;
    struct student_s* next;   
};
```

simply declares `struct student_s` and equivalent to declaration without the typedef specifier

```
struct student_s {
    char* name;
    int age;
    double height;
    struct student_s* next;   
};
```

It does does not introduce a typedef name in the scope.

Comment: I understand what this code does, that it does not introduce a typedef name. This does not answer the question. Does failing to introduce a typedef name in and of itself qualify as a violation of a syntax rule or constraint and hence must result in a diagnostic (5.1.1.3 Diagnostics).

Comment: @David Hammen  What?!!! I showed that it is a correct declaration. What is the problem with you?

Comment: Vlad, sorry, I didn't read your answer that way. Upon re-reading, I see that that is exactly what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

this typedef:

```
typedef struct student_s {
    char* name;
    int age;
    double height;
    struct student_s* next;
};
```

yields the following:

```
warning useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]
```

So the syntax is acceptable, but without a declarer, the code is trash